# (Python3) How can I recreate an Image from pixels values?

Tags: python-3.x, python-imaging-library

I have this code:

```
from PIL import Image
im = Image.open('red-flower.jpg', 'r')
pix_val = list(im.getdata())
pix_val_flat = [x for sets in pix_val for x in sets]
print(pix_val_flat)
```

It takes an image of a red flower and reads the pixel values, then stores it in the variable "pix_val" and then pix_val_flat flattens the image, thus making a list of pixels cleaner and not a list like this, [(R,G,B,A),(R,G,B,A)].

So how can I recreate the image with these pixel values?

Answer (score 0):

You are interested in Pixel Access - https://pillow.readthedocs.io/en/5.2.x/reference/PixelAccess.html.

Presuming you know the width, height and mode of the image -

```
from PIL import Image
im = Image.new('RGB')
px = im.load()
for x in range(0, w):
    for y in range(0, h):
        px[x, y] = (255, 0, 0)
```

I imagine you might also prefer to use this to read the pixels as well.

```
from PIL import Image
im = Image.open('hopper.jpg')
px = im.load()
pix_val_flat = []
for x in range(0, im1.width):
    for y in range(0, im1.height):
        pix_val_flat.append(px[x, y])
```